# Apache on 18.04 LTS | Change where web files are stored and served from?

Tags: partitioning, apache2, php, raid, apache2.4

I'm making a move from WAMP to LAMP, and run a custom PHP application that uploads media files to users on a LAN. I plan to have two [volumes](https://www.maketecheasier.com/difference-between-disk-drive-volume-partition-image/) in my sever. One will be the Ubuntu system and apps drive, and the other is a RAID 10 configuration for web file storage.

1) How do I [configure Apache](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/urlmapping.html) to serve files from the RAID volume, instead of from the volume where Ubuntu boots and runs from?

2) Is this configured after I install Apache or do I need to specify the location serving web files during the Apache installation?

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you know apache on windows, configuration is the same, you have a bunch of config files that tell apache which domains to serve, where to find content, who may access, etc. You can change the config any time you want. During installation some default settings will be put into `/etc/apache2/` to get you started which you can change to your liking.

In ubuntu the structure is probably different from what you are used to in WAMP. Put your vhost definitions into `/etc/apache2/sites-available/` and run `a2ensite site-name` (site-name is the name of your file in sites-available) and reload apache service (`sudo systemctl reload apache2.service`). Inside your vhost, just point `DocumentRoot` or an `Alias` to your second partition. You may need a `<Directory /path/to/document/root>` definition to allow access to your document root.

Alternatively, you can just mount your second partition to `/var/www` which is the default location for apaches document root. This will put your web files automatically on your second partition without changing any of the default apache configuration.

Comment: Thanks. I like the alternative option. I think that is likely the best scenario. I'll give it a try and let you know how it goes.